# How to run wayland(weston) on another display

Tags: wayland, weston

When I want to run second xsession on display 1 I go to tty2 and then:

```
export DISPLAY=:1
startx -- :1
```

.xinitrc contains `exec startxfce4`

Is it possible to run in similar way Wayland/Weston ? Does exist equivalent for startx ? When I run only Weston I probably get a blank screen so I may need to use  compatible desktop environment - Hawaii

Comment: I too have similar issue right now, finding startx equivalent in wayland/weston to start separate session in another display?
Ex: 
Display=:0 prog &
Display=:1 prog &

Comment: weston is not x, it may be possible with the output section of [weston.ini](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man5/weston.ini.5.html)